# Storing HTML in mysql tables

Tags: html, mysql, windows, ms-word

What I wanna do is, to copy-paste word document's styled content to mysql database as HTML markup.

After research found this resource

http://word2cleanhtml.com

I wonder, is there any **free** Windows application that does exactly same thing as this resource?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah here: http://word-to-html.com/

Comment: I need free app, not paid one

Comment: It is free. If you pay you get free updates and support, but you don't have to pay.

Comment: You can always just "Save As Web Page", you'll get an html page, graphics, and list of files in XML.